# Why does the CAN ID 7DF not work yet 7E0 does?

Tags: can, pid-controller

I am using https://github.com/Ircama/ELM327-emulator in order to simulate the can/elm327 response from a toyota euris hybrid.

My understanding is that the header 7DF should be used when requesting service PID's. Yet when I make the request `test 7DF 02 01 0C` for engine RPM, I receive no response.

If I make the request again with header `7E0` I receive the response `7E8 04 41 0C 23 82 \r\r>` which is correct.

Why is this the case?

Comment: ask the author of the software ... they should know how the emulator behaves

Comment: a question about the behavior of some software is not an electronics design question